# Authenticating to a password protected NFS share

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I am trying to set up a PersistentVolume against a password protected NFS export. When I try to create the PersistentVolume, I get the following error message:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pv.yaml":
> PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a
> PersistentVolume: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.secret"

How do I specify the secret in the PV?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: nfs-auth-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: name_base64
  password: password_base64


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /mnt/Storage/nfs-test2
    server: ip_address
  secret:
    secretName: nfs-auth-secret
```